# iOS6/UIWebview redirecting to wrong page of App

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, ios6

Our app relies on UIWebview to return to the app following a phone call initiated by the user. After consulting a number of developers, we did not make any changes for iOS6, expecting the app to work fine.

Now, the following has happened:

1) UIWebview IS still working - bringing the user back into the app when they end a call

2) However, the app is directing the user to the wrong screen - it is taking it to the screen FOLLOWING the one the user should see. The crucial screen where the user can log their phone call is not showing up.

3) The only exception seems to be when the user logs out and logs back in - in this case they can see the correct screen ONLY once, and then the next time they call they go to the wrong screen again.

I am not a coder but after looking through the code as it stands, it looks like this is one of three (nearly identical) snippets of code that should be calling the End Call screen at the end of a phone call but under iOS6 is not:

```
- (IBAction)onCall:(id)sender
{
DashCaller *caller = [[DashCaller alloc] init];

NSString *callNumber = _phone.number;
if (!callNumber)
{
    callNumber = @"No Phone number";
}
else if (callNumber.length == 0)
{
    callNumber = @"No Phone number";
}
else
{
    callNumber = [callNumber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

DashDelegate.calledPhone = _phone;
DashDelegate.callLogVC.delegate = _viewController;
DashDelegate.callStartDate = [NSDate date];

NSUserDefaults *setting = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *blockNumber = [setting valueForKey:BLOCK_NUMBER];
NSURL *url = nil;

if (blockNumber.boolValue)
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@%@", kStringBlockNumber, callNumber]];
else {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", callNumber]];
}

[caller callTelURL:url];
}
```

Specifically, the line "DashDelegate.callLogVC.delegate = _viewController;" seems like it should be calling the CallLogVC view but instead it is going to the screen that should appear right after that view.

Anyone with thoughts on what to change (that could have been affected by iOS6)? The app is fully functional in iOS5. And, why might the app show this page only once after a log-out-log-in and then stop showing it?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.... Please be more specific.... And its not clear at all about what you wanna tell....

Comment: Hi Saalis! My question is: Before, when the app returned, it went to a Call Log screen. Now, with exactly the same code under iOS6, it comes back into the app (as expected) but skips the intermediate Call Log screen and goes back to wherever the user launched the call from. It is skipping the screen that stores the crucial information the app handles - I am trying to figure out why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To go back to original app you can use telprompt:// instead of tel:// - The tell prompt will prompt the user first, but when the call is finished it will go back to your app:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

You may also try these app delegate methods for restoring application after the call finishes.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! My issue is, even if I go into the DashCaller method and change it to use the telprompt instead of UIWebview, this problem seems to be happening POST returning to the app - It is just not going to the correct page, when before it was. Any thoughts on why that is given the notes above?

Comment: actually, it is difficult for me to understand your problem and present a solution.... As it seems you are from non-objective c non-ios background, but still I feel I can help you if you may post some screenshots of what you want and what you are getting.... Also, kindly post the code of the above methods listed if they are present in class named with AppDelegate. If you want we can have a skype...